# JQ Aggregations and Crosstabs

Tags: jq

I have some data thus:

```
[
  {
    "count": 4,
    "trial_status": "Follow up",
    "date": "2015-06-06"
  },
  {
    "count": 3,
    "trial_status": "Hold",
    "date": "2015-06-06"
  },
  {
    "count": 2,
    "trial_status": "Trial",
    "date": "2015-06-06"
  },
  {
    "count": 1,
    "trial_status": "Trial + Confirm",
    "date": "2015-06-06"
  }....
```

which I would like to transform to

```
{"2015-06-06": {"Trial + Confirm": 1, "Follow Up": 4, "Hold": 3, "Trial": 2}}
```

I am not making much headway with any of my approaches so would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
group_by(.date) | map({
    key: .[0].date,
    value: map({
        key: .trial_status,
        value: .count
    }) | from_entries
}) | from_entries
```

The key is to use `from_entries` to build up the mappings.  <strike>This is the only way you can set up "properties"/keys by name.</strike>  You just need to generate the key/value pairs that will make up the object.

---

Santiago points out that you can dynamically set properties by name with a special syntax.  This would work too.

```
group_by(.date) | map({
    (.[0].date): map({
        (.trial_status): .count
    }) | add
}) | add
```

Comment: Great answer! Just as a pointless interesting feature: `from_entries` is not the only way to set key names programatically: `{(foo): bar} | add` also does the same. While I personally prefer `from_entries` due to readability concerns, this script's behaviour is identical to yours: `group_by(.date) | map({(.[0].date): map({(.trial_status): .count}) | add}) | add`

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip, I forgot about that syntax.  I was trying something else which did not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce), [destructuring variable binding](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...) and [setpath](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#setpath(PATHS;VALUE))

```
reduce .[] as {count:$c, trial_status:$s, date:$d} (
  {}
; setpath([$d, $s]; $c)
)
```

If this filter is in `filter.jq` and `data.json` contains the sample data then the command

```
$ jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
{
  "2015-06-06": {
    "Follow up": 4,
    "Hold": 3,
    "Trial": 2,
    "Trial + Confirm": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find your head spinning because of maps inside maps, or if you prefer a direct approach (which in this case at least also happens to be fast and simple), consider using `reduce` like so:

  `reduce .[] as $o
    ({}; . + {($o.date): (.[$o.date] + {($o.trial_status): $o.count} )})`

Thanks to jq's null semantics, this can be simplified and shortened to:

  `reduce .[] as $o
    ({}; .[$o.date] += { ($o.trial_status): $o.count } )`